# Is there a way to add our own overlay to Googlemap v2 - android

Tags: java, android, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to know Is it possible to add our own `overlay`with our own properties in to `google map v2` in `android`?

I did google search everywhere I think but nothing found similar this. except all use in built `Marker`, `GroundOverlay`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add overlays like in V1. Only solution is use Markers and info window. We can modify info window content with different layout files so still can use like different overlays. To manage different overlays I used hashmap and array list. Each Myoverlay class has own arraylist of markers. Then that array add to the hashmap with a overlay name.